# How to replace all instance of string '&user_story=x' using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this -

```
var string = 'callback&user_story=1&user_story=2&user_story=100&user_story=a&user_story=john';
```

`&user_story=x` (Here x can be anything) can repeat n number of times.

How to replace this `'&user_story=x'` with a blank value.

What would be regex for it in JS?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Try your code on `var str ="callback&user_story=1&user_story=2&user_story=100&user_story=a&user_story=john&joundills_special_param=isthisstillhere";`. It will remove my additional parameter, so isn't a correct answer.

Comment: @Joundill , thank you for pointing it out . Noted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex looks like this:

```js
var string = 'callback&user_story=1&user_story=2&user_story=100&user_story=a&user_story=john';

var re = /&user_story=.*?(?=&|$)/g

console.log(string.replace(re, ""));
```

Broken down:

`/&user_story=.*?(?=&|$)/g`

`&user_story=` - checks whether the match starts with `"&user_story="`

`.*?` - matches any number of any characters, but the `?` makes it non-greedy, so it will find as few of these characters before finding the next part of the regex

`(?=&|$)` - the brackets make this a group, and `?=` means it's a lookahead, i.e. it won't actually add matches to the regex match, but just checks to see they're there. It will match either another `&`, or the end of the string (symbolised by `$`).

`g` - is a flag which tells the regex to check the entire string, and not stop after just finding one match.